# Gráfico primefaces Spark Charts

Tags: java, primefaces, front-end

Estou usando primefaces para fazer meus gráficos, porém tenho um problema.
Os gráficos geram certinho, mas eu tenho que passar o mouse para exibir os valores como no exemplo a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que os valores sempre apareçam lá, independente se passe o mouse ou não.